# Paste Pivot Table from excel to Powerpoint

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpoint, vba

I'm trying to create a tool that will automatically create a powerpoint presentation. Basically I have an existing powerpoint file and I need to paste several pivot tables on each slide specified. For now, I am testing to paste the pivot table in slide 3 with the code below. But I get some error:

```
Sub Presentation()

Dim PPApp  As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim sPath As String
Dim sSaveTo As String
Dim sFileName As String
Dim sDate As String
Dim FinalName As String
'On Error Resume Next
Dim pvt As PivotTable

Set pvt = Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

sPath = Range("RangePath").Value
sSaveTo = Range("RangeSaveTo").Value
sDate = Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM")

sFileName = Range("RangeFileName").Value
FinalName = sSaveTo & sFileName

    Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    'Reference active presentation
    Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open(sPath)

    pvt.TableRange1.Copy
    ' Paste chart  to Slide #3
    With PPPres.Slides(3).Shapes.PasteSpecial '<~~~~~This is where I get an error

        .Left = 45
        .Top = 34

    End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'MsgBox ("Presentation has been created!"), vbOKOnly

PPApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs FinalName & " " & sDate
waiting (7)
PPApp.Quit   

End Sub
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

[image]

Would someone know how I can deal with pasting the Pivot Table on a specific slide?

Comment: Were you even able to do this manually?  I guess there are ways to accomplish that but it's going to take you some work.  I'd suggest you start by [**Googling** "add pivot table to powerpoint"](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=add+pivot+table+to+powerpoint+slide).

Comment: Hi, this seems to be working but I think I am doing something wrong with shapes. My pivot table is already existing in excel and I need to copy it and paste to an existing powerpoint file (specific slide). Which in this case, slide 3.

Comment: what's working about it?

Comment: The copying of pivot table. As it is selecting the pivot table in excel. The one that is not working is With PPPres.Slides(3).Shapes.PasteSpecial. Which I am not that really familiar.

Comment: It's working because it's hasn't "done anything" yet (ie., left Excel).  Pasting is a pretty important part of "copy & pasting".  You can do it, using help from the link I provided, but not everything can be pasted everywhere haphazardly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 With PPPres.Slides(3).Shapes
     .PasteSpecial
    .Left = 45
    .Top = 34
End With
```

Something like this ? In the example above you left `.PasteSpecial` on the same row `With PPPres.Slides(3).Shapes` .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, when I tried, it gives me method not found.

Comment: I assume you didn't test this?  Is it a guess?

Comment: @ashleedawg yes, a guess from past experiences of `With` specifics

Comment: @Sevpoint look [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba) maybe it will help, though it will paste a picture, not a pivot.